# How to debug React Native Expo App in VSC

Tags: javascript, react-native, debugging, expo

I have the packager attached to the android emulator. Everything seems to be connected but breakpoints aren't hitting when code is hit. What steps do you take to attach the packager?

These are the steps I took: 
     Opened expo app on android emulator.
     Created attach to packager config:

```
{
  "name": "Attach to packager",
  "request": "attach",
  "type": "reactnative",
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "port": 19000
}
```

Ran debugger using the config above
     Enabled remote debugging in emulator.
     Opened Camera inside app

Nothing hit and that's where I put the breakpoint in the code
[Image of VSC and Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tObBV.png)